# Using Powerquery to link reference table to column headers of data table to create averages

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a data table, that contains survey data with the following column headers:

```
Answerid | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3
       1            3            4            5
```

And a reference table that links question categories to the questions:

```
Question 1 | Category A
Question 2 | Category B
Question 3 | Category B
```

Now I would like to view results as averages on a Category level. For example in a bar chart where each bar shows the average value for that category.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what specific problem are you having? Please [edit] your question to include the code you've tried, and any relevant error messages / outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Load in reference range with no column headers and call it Reference.  Load in data table.  Right click first column, choose Unpivot other columns. Home...Merge Queries... Merge to table Reference and click on Question column at top and bottom to link them. Expand results by clicking arrow box at top of new column. Right click column with Category, Group By, use average and apply to the column with numerical field.  Add your own chart as desired

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"AnswerID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"},Reference,{"Column1"},"RefernceTable",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded RefernceTable" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "RefernceTable", {"Column2"}, {"Column2"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded RefernceTable", {"Column2"}, {{"Average", each List.Average([Value]), type number}})
in #"Grouped Rows"
```